# Does the below-quoted fact follow from the countable subadditivity property of probability measure $\mathbb{P}$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, inequality, rational-numbers

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $a$ and $b$ be two rationals (i.e. $a$,$b$ $\in \mathbb{Q}$) such that $a<b$ and $(X_n)$ be a sequence of random variables defined on the above-defined measurable space. Set:
\begin{equation}
\Lambda_{a,b}=\{\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n\geq b; \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n \leq a\}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\Lambda=\bigcup\limits_{a<b} \Lambda_{a,b}
\end{equation}

Therefore, I "read" $\Lambda$ as follows:

**there exists at least a pair of rationals $a$, $b$ ($a<b$) such that $\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n\geq b; \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n \leq a$**, that is

\begin{equation}
\Lambda=\{\limsup\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n> \liminf\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}X_n\}
\end{equation}

I am given that $\mathbb{P}(\Lambda_{a,b})=0$ $\forall a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a<b$. And, at this point, I know that one can state that

> "$\mathbb{P}(\Lambda)=0$, since all rational pairs are countable"

I interpret the above statement in the following way, but I am not sure whether it is correct or not.

---

Since:

- $\mathbb{P}(\Lambda_{a,b})=0$ $\forall  a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a<b$;
- $\bigcup\limits_{a<b}\Lambda_{a,b}$ is a countable union, since rationals are 
   countable by definition;

*by countable subadditivity property of probability measure $\mathbb{P}$*, it follows that:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(\Lambda)=\mathbb{P}\big(\bigcup\limits_{a<b} \Lambda_{a,b}\big)\leq \sum\limits_{a<b}\mathbb{P}\big(\Lambda_{a,b}\big)=0
\end{equation}
where $\sum\limits_{a<b}\mathbb{P}\big(\Lambda_{a,b}\big)=0$ follows from the fact that I am given that $\mathbb{P}(\Lambda_{a,b})=0$ $\forall a, b \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $a<b$.

Hence, since probability lies by definition between $0$ and $1$, $\mathbb{P}(\Lambda)\leq 0$ "means" that:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(\Lambda)=0
\end{equation}

---

***Is my reasoning correct?***

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your confirmation. So, can I say that subadditivity property of probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ is by definition a "countable" subadditivity property? That is, if for example $a$,$b$ were two numbers belonging to a **NOT** countable set, could I have made the same reasoning (that is, applying the subadditivity property of $\mathbb{P}$ so as to get to my result $\mathbb{P}(\Lambda)=0$)? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: The argument fails for uncountable unions. For example if $X$ hss normal distribution then $P(X=x)=0$ for a ll $x$ but when you take the union of $(X=x)$ over all real numbers the probability becomes $1$.

Comment: That's a perfect example, I got it. Thank you a lot for your time and help @KaviRamaMurthy